# Vue2.js - how to get selected options from a json

Tags: vuejs2

I have a form in vue.js with a multiple selection and i need to match the json i send when i need to update the form with the correct options.

Basically this is the form select(and it works when saving a new object), `options` is an array of objects

```
<b-form-group id="supplier-group" label="Label">
                    <b-form-select v-model="form.suppliers" id="suppliers" required multiple>

                    <option v-for="option in options" 
                    :key="option.supplierId"
                    :value="option.supplierId">{{option.name}}</option>
                </b-form-select>
```

Now when i need to update and object, I retrieve it from a web service and i usually make this method:

```
getObject(id){ // to retrieve the objet
            var url = this.$attrs.url + id

            this.$http.get(url)
            .then(response => this.populateForm(response))
        },
        populateForm(res){
            var values = res.data
            console.log(values.suppliers) //it's an array of objects
            this.form.name = values.name
            this.form.description = values.description

            this.form.suppliers = values.suppliers //i should make the options selected..

        }
```

But i see the options of the selected, but i need a way to make them selected based on the `supplierId` field of the suppliers array.

Answer (score 0):

For each option you have, you need to calculate if the option is present in the saved selection:

```
<option v-for="option in options":key="option.supplierId" :value="option.supplierId" :selected="isSelected(option.supplierId)">{{option.name}}</option>
```

You will provide a function to search the supplier id inside your selected suppliers' collection (isSelected have to return a boolean)

Comment: thanks, i made the function and it works, but the options are rendered before `this.form.suppliers`is assigned the array... i have to call the IsSelected after...